# Python regular MIMEText email works but not MIMEMultiPart

Tags: python, email, smtp

I have the following Python code which works and can send an email inside a company network:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#Define the message
msg = MIMEText("Email Body")
msg['Subject'] = "Subject Line"
msg['From'] = "no-reply@company.com"
msg['To'] = "my_email@company.com"

#Connect and send the email
server = smtplib.SMTP('blahblahblah.company.com',25)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.sendmail("my_email@company.com", "no-reply@company.com", msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Now I want to add a PDF attachment to it. I've looked at many threads on MIMEMultiPart emails for sending attachments, so I've mocked up that version:

```
import smtplib
import os
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

#Define the message
pdf_output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Form.pdf")
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = "Subject Line"
msg['From'] = 'no-reply@company.com'
msg['To'] = "my_email@company.com"
msg.attach(MIMEText("Email Body"))
with open(pdf_output_path, "rb") as fil:
    part = MIMEApplication(
        fil.read(),
        Name=os.path.basename(pdf_output_path)
    )
part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(pdf_output_path)
msg.attach(part)

#Connect and send the email
server = smtplib.SMTP('blahblahblah.company.com',25)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.sendmail("my_email@company.com", "no-reply@company.com", msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

However this doesn't send an email at all. It does not crash or leave any output or error messages, but does not send an email. I get the same result when I comment out the part of the code that adds the attachment.

Does anyone have an idea on what is going on? Normally I'd just look up the error, but with the absence of any feedback I am not only at a loss but legitimately curious why it successfully runs but does nothing.

Comment: Works for me.  Maybe the server marks it as spam, or anti-virus quarantines it to examine the attachment.

Comment: I was wondering about that. Emails weren't showing up in my junk mail or anything, figured they would at least show up there. I actually tinkered with it a bit and was able to get it to work by changing "no-reply@company.com" to my email. Not sure why it's specifically the combination of the no-reply and the pdf attachment that get the email flagged, but whatever. Do you know of any alternative generic email names I could maybe use in place of no-reply that might not get flagged?